# R Shiny Foreign Character Encoding

Tags: r, encoding, shiny, shiny-server

We are collecting musician data which would have musician names in foreign characters (Spanish, Chinese, Korean, etc). I guess I have to specify the encoding, where I got stuck. Below is my temporary solution, which works for English + Spanish names.

```
#if I don't specify encoding = "Latin-1", they will not display any foreign names correctly. 
#By setting encoding = "Latin-1", it makes sure Spanish names display correctly. 
#However, it doesn't work for Asian characters. 
dd = fread(paste0("/shiny-server/testingfile.csv"), encoding = "Latin-1")

#to download it and show names correctly, I also need to set fileEncoding = "latin1"
output$map = downloadHandler(
filename = function(){
  paste("Mapping Request ",Sys.time(),".csv",sep="")
},
content = function(file){
  write.csv(data,file,row.names = F,fileEncoding = "latin1")
}
)
```

I am wondering is there a way to make any foreign names showing correctly? Or I have to set encoding for each language (which is not practical). When I set encoding = "UTF-8", it only display English name correctly.

Btw, our Shiny-server is Linux.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: try to convert `testingfile.csv' into UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: In Linux system, you can use function `detectFileEncoding` in `Ruchardet` package to detect the encoding in original file. Then call system command  `iconv -f old_encoding -t UTF-8 old_file > new_file` to convert your files into UTF-8 format.